# grails: grailsui : cannot access dataTable outside <gui> tag

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I tried to access Datatable outside gui tag, but failed.
Could some tell me why?

thanks.

the code like this:

```
<gui:dataTable id="myDataTable" .../>
<script>
    var data = GRAILSUI.myDataTable;
    alert("hi, " + data);

</script>
```

it ends with "hi, undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import the resources correctly ?

in the header  ?

Comment: yes, i did. every thing else is working.  i guess this has something to do with javascript object that is defined.